# Express Route 404 Error But Correct Routing?

Tags: node.js, express

I tried almost everything and nothing seems to work, read every tutorial and SOF post. Been scratching my hair out over it. i get a 404 for this route specifically and i cant find the issue.

app.js

```
var watchRouter = require('./routes/watch');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/search', indexRouter);
app.use('/watch/:anime/:id', watchRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

watch.js

````
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:anime/:id', function(req, res) {
});```

module.exports = router;
````

Comment: You already had `/:anime/:id` where the router was mounted, so your get should just be `/`. Also you don't need to handle 404s yourself, that's what Express does if it can't match a route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your route in watch.js is `'/:anime/:id'`, you need to change `app.use('/watch/:anime/:id', watchRouter);` to `app.use('/watch', watchRouter);` in app.js, otherwise your complete route would be `'/watch/:anime/:id/:anime/:id'`.

So, for example:

app.js:

```
app.use('/watch', watchRouter);
```

watch.js:

```
router.get('/:anime/:id', (req, res) => {
  return res.json({ anime: req.params.anime, id: req.params.id });
});
```